# Swift 4 - JSON parsing with Codable protocol (nested data)

Tags: ios, json, swift, decode, swift4

I am trying to update myself and use modern and recent Swift 4 features.

That is why I am training with the `Codable` protocol in order to parse JSON and directly map my model object.

First of all, I did some research and self learning.

This article helped me a lot : [Ultimate guide](http://benscheirman.com/2017/06/ultimate-guide-to-json-parsing-with-swift-4/)

I just need to focus on the "Com" array.

As you can notice, it contains some nested object. I named them Flash Info.

It is defined by :

- endDate
- text
- image[]
- title
- productionDate
- id

So here is my Codable Struct :

```
struct FlashInfo : Codable {

    let productionDate: String
    let endDate: String
    let text: String
    let title: String
    let id: String
}
```

First of all, I was trying to parse it without the array of Images, I will handle it later.

So here is my method :

```
func getFlashInfo(success: @escaping (Array<FlashInfo>)  -> Void) {

        var arrayFlash = [FlashInfo]()

        Alamofire.request(URL_TEST, method: .get).responseJSON { response in
            if response.value != nil {
                if let data = response.data, let utf8Text = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                    print("Data: \(utf8Text)")
                }

                //let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                // let flash = try! decoder.decode(FlashInfo.self, from: response.data!)
                // arrayFlash.append(flash)

                success(arrayFlash)
            } else {
                print("error getFlashInfo")
            }
        }
    }
```

I don't know how to handle the fact that I only need the "Com" array and how to iterate through all nested objects in order to fill my array in the callback.

I mean, will the decode protocol iterate through each objects ?

Am I clear?

EDIT: JSON as text

```
{"Test": [], "Toto": [], "Com": [{"endDate": "2017-06-27T08:00:00Z", "text": "John Snow is getting married", "image": ["895745-test.png", "632568-test.png"], "titre": "We need you!", "productionDate": "2017-07-02T16:16:23Z", "id": "9686"}, {"endDate": "2017-07-27T08:00:00Z", "text": "LOL TEST", "image": ["895545-test.png", "632568-test.png"], "titre": "She needs you!", "productionDate": "2017-08-02T16:16:23Z", "id": "9687"},{"endDate": "2017-06-27T08:00:00Z", "text": "iOS swift", "image": ["895775-test.png", "638568-test.png"], "titre": "They need you!", "productionDate": "2017-07-02T16:16:23Z", "id": "9688"}], "Yt": []}
```

Comment: Add json as text please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the quickest way is just to define an *incomplete* `Response` type as well. For instance:

```
struct Response: Codable {
    let Com: [FlashInfo]
}

struct FlashInfo: Codable {
    let productionDate: String
    let endDate: String
    let text: String
    let title: String
    let id: String
    let image: [String] = [] // Ignored for now.

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case productionDate, endDate, text, id
        case title = "titre" // Fix for JSON typo ;)
    }
}
```

and decode it like this:

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let response = try! decoder.decode(Response.self, from: data)
print(response.Com)
```

This worked great with the test data you provided (just watch out for the *typo* in the `title` field):

```
let json = """
{"Test": [], "Toto": [], "Com": [{"endDate": "2017-06-27T08:00:00Z", "text": "John Snow is getting married", "image": ["895745-test.png", "632568-test.png"], "titre": "We need you!", "productionDate": "2017-07-02T16:16:23Z", "id": "9686"}, {"endDate": "2017-07-27T08:00:00Z", "text": "LOL TEST", "image": ["895545-test.png", "632568-test.png"], "titre": "She needs you!", "productionDate": "2017-08-02T16:16:23Z", "id": "9687"},{"endDate": "2017-06-27T08:00:00Z", "text": "iOS swift", "image": ["895775-test.png", "638568-test.png"], "titre": "They need you!", "productionDate": "2017-07-02T16:16:23Z", "id": "9688"}], "Yt": []}
"""
let data = json.data(using: .utf8)!
```

Comment: Wow... I wasn't thinking that way, it feels so obvious. Thank you @Paulo Mattos. This is working perfectly. I will update all my web service calls now.

Comment: Is it better to make all properties optional or the Codable protocol handles it?