# Swift JSON to Model Class

Tags: json, swift, parsing

I want to put all data from my JSON to model class. How i can do that? All fields and my code i will put right below!

**Model**

```
class FacebookUser: NSObject {
    var first_name: String?
    var id: String?
    var last_name: String?
    var name: String?
    var picture: String?

    init(dictionary: [String: AnyObject]) {
        self.first_name = dictionary["first_name"] as? String
        self.id = dictionary["id"] as? String
        self.last_name = dictionary["last_name"] as? String
        self.name = dictionary["name"] as? String
        self.picture = dictionary["picture"] as? String
    }
}
```

**JSON EXAMPLE**

```
{
    "picture" : {
        "data" : {
            "height" : 50,
            "is_silhouette" : false,
            "url" : "link",
            "width" : 50
        }
    },
    "name" : "George Heinz",
    "last_name" : "Heinz",
    "id" : "1860499320637949",
    "first_name" : "George"
}
```

Comment: Make your class implement Codable and then read up on how to implement that protocol properly. Also, no need to subclass NSObject

Comment: Are all the fields really optional `var`s? It's make your life easier if fields that must be present use non-optional `let`… e.g. `let id: String`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift 4 - JSON parsing with Codable protocol (nested data)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46935354/swift-4-json-parsing-with-codable-protocol-nested-data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I assume that you have json in `Data` format and All field `Optional`

Create following decodable json model class which are used to decode your json data.

```
struct PictureJson: Decodable {
    var picture         : Data?
    var name            : String?
    var last_name       : String?
    var id              : String?
    var first_name      : String?
}

struct Data: Decodable {
    var data            : ImageData?
}

struct ImageData : Decodable {
    var height          : Int?
    var is_silhouette   : Bool?
    var url             : String?
    var width           : Int?
}
```

And write following code to decode your json

```
do {
    let picture = try JSONDecoder().decode(PictureJson.self, from: jsonData!) as? PictureJson
     print(picture!.picture!.data)
        
} catch {
    // print error here.  
}
```

Comment: i get this error now... "Cannot convert value of type 'JSON' to expected argument type 'Data'"
i got JSON from FB auth..

Comment: @GeorgeHeints, Please check JSON's super class and make sure it should be data. If JSON is [String: Any] then your need to encode it to data form.

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest url for creating model.

1. http://www.jsoncafe.com
2. https://app.quicktype.io

here you put your json then convert.

Comment: jsoncafe.com does not exist anymore