# Cannot assign value of type '[JSON]' to type '[MyStruct]'

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui, alamofire, swifty-json

I'm learning to use SwiftyJSON and I'm trying to convert the resulted values into an array of MyStruct. However, whenever I try that, it tells me that they are not compatible. How can I convert [JSON] into [MyStruct]?

```
class TreatmentsManager: ObservableObject {

 @Published var treatments = [Treatment]()
 func testAlamofire() {
  AF.request("http://dermaservice.theappmaster.com/Tratamiento.ashx").response { response in
    switch response.result {
    case .success(let value):
        let json = JSON(value)
        if let treatmentArray = json["Tratamientos"].array {
            self.treatments = treatmentArray
         //[MyStruct] type /= [JSON] type
        }
    case .failure(let error):
        print(error)
    }}}}
```

Comment: You have to convert your json to model formate then you can assign it to your model. Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/51319533/4754213

Comment: Just saw you edit. Thanks!

Comment: Check edited answers.

Comment: @VishalPatel, I looked at the link. How can I incorporate that to Alamofire?

Comment: Check your hangout.

Comment: @VishalPatel, I'm sorry: what do you mean by hangout?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227847/discussion-between-vishal-patel-and-nico-cobelo).

Comment: Oh, never mind. I figured it out. Thank you so much! I'll post the answer shortly

Comment: Great capture and welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @VishalPatel, i figured out how to do it:

```
class TreatmentsManager: ObservableObject {

  @Published var treatments = [Treatment]()
  func testAlamofire() {
    AF.request("http://dermaservice.theappmaster.com/Tratamiento.ashx").response { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let value):
            do {
                let results = try JSONDecoder().decode(TreatmentList.self, from: value!)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                  self.treatments = results.Tratamientos
                  }
                } catch {
                print(error)
                }
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Where TreatmentList is a struct containing [Treatments].
So there is not need to use SwiftyJSON